# ItemSeparatorComponent - Call back for each row

Tags: react-native

How do I make `ItemSeparatorComponent` prop of `FlatList` get called for each row, so that one can customize for each row. Something similar of what [renderSeparator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderseparator) prop of deprecated `ListView`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same requirement, turns out you can pass a function as well:

```
renderSeparator = ({leadingItem, section})=>{
  if (section.noSeparator || !leadingItem.noSeparator)
    return null;
  return <Separator />;
};

render(){
  return <SectionList
      renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
      sections={this.sections}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
  />;
}
```

Comment: In reality, you're still passing a component, since the function is effectively just a functional component.

Answer (score -2):

To show `ItemSeparatorComponent`, make your own separator or declare inbuild separator from react-native. The separator need to be put just above the `FlatList` so that it renders in the right place. The separators are visible at the end and beginning of the list. Below is the code for separator in `FlatList`:

```
{/* ... */}

render()
{
    return(

        {/* ... */}

        <SeparatorComponent />  //separator component
        <FlatList
            ItemSeparatorComponent={SeparatorComponent} // assign the separator here  

            {/* ... */}

            />
    )
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, but the question I want call back for each row

Comment: everytime the control comes to render()... do you want to add different type of separator after each row?

Comment: Yes, the render method gets called for each row, but I don't have the row data in the render method

Comment: you can extract row data from the renderItem prop. so inorder to call customized separator make global variable, assign that variable with the customized separator and put it above the FlatList. If you need different separator for each row then put it in return of renderItem.

Comment: So there is nothing similar to  renderSeparator of ListView ?